# DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged does not fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, ascx, asp.net-webpages

I have MVC4 Web application and i am rendering a partial view(.ascx) inside a .cshtml page. I have added a dropdownlist which has OnSelectedIndexChanged  and it never fires. please see the code below

**Dashboard.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Dashboard.ascx.cs" Inherits="iSPYCMS.Views.Dashboard" EnableViewState="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head id="Head1" runat="server">  
<title>Charts Example</title>  
</head>  
<body style="padding:50px;background-color:white">         

<form id="form1" runat="server">  

    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="cmbTypeSeletion" Height="16px" Width="190px" EnableViewState="true" Enabled="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbTypeSeletion_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="Downloads" Value="Downloads"> </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="Plays" Value="Plays"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="Completion" Value="Completion"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
<div>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"> </script>  
    <asp:Literal ID="ltScripts" runat="server"></asp:Literal>  
    <div id="chart_div">  
    </div>  
</div>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

**Dashboard.ascx.cs**

```
namespace iSPYCMS.Views
{
  public partial class Dashboard : ViewUserControl
  {
    protected void cmbTypeSeletion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div>
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/Dashboard.ascx")
</div>
```

Comment: you are mixing webforms with MVC.. not good

Comment: Yes i know in fact i had to use google chart and i could not find any good example of MVC for this so i used user control

Comment: google charts doesn't need webforms/postbacks at all

Comment: i need to add dropdown and on the basis of that selection i have to change the chart data

Comment: bind an ajax request on the dropdown change event

Answer (score 0):

Set AutoPostBack="True" for the dropdown list

Comment: <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="cmbTypeSeletion" Height="16px" Width="190px" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" Enabled="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbTypeSeletion_SelectedIndexChanged">